# Why are the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form 'obvious'?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, intuition

In my book on complex analysis I'm asked to prove the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form, which I did. However, at the end of the question the author asks why these relations are 'almost obvious'.

Now I get the derivation using chain rules and also the idea of approach along a circle and along a radial line and then equating. But the fact that the author asks this question to me suggests that there is an even simpler way of seeing this. That or maybe the author just regards one of these approaches to be 'almost obvious'.

So I'm looking for a more intuitive (so it also does not need to be 100% rigorous) way of thinking about the Cauchy-Riemann relations in polar form. These  relations are

$$u_r=\frac{1}{r}v_\theta, \quad \frac{1}{r}u_\theta = -v_r$$

Comment: Well, it would help if you wrote out what you got for the equations in polar form.

Comment: You should add what the book is calling the "polar Cauchy-Riemann equations", since there are a number of possibilities (polar arguments, polar functions, both...).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See the edit

Comment: As Wikipedia points out, this is equivalent to $$\frac{df}{dr}=\frac{1}{ir}\frac{df}{d\theta}$$ where $f(r,\theta)=u(r,\theta)+iv(r,\theta)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oke, but I'm not seeing why that result is particularly obvious given that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews To be clear, I do see that what you mention is equivalent to the CR relation I wrote down, I'm just not seeing why, when someone tells me '$f$ is differentiable' I should immediately think 'Ah then clearly $\frac{df}{dr}=\frac{1}{ir}\frac{df}{d\theta}$'

Comment: We have $\frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = \frac{z}{r}$, and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial\theta} = iz$, so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} = ir\frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$. Hence $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}(z) = f'(z)\cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} = irf'(z)\cdot \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} = ir\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(z).$$ Not sure whether that kind of thing is what the author had in mind.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your response. I do think this is as good as it's going to get. To me this is obvious insofar as it only requiring basic calculus rules, but then again that is true for a lot of the exercises I've had to do so far. So I'm still not sure why the author thought that this was particularly obvious, but so be it.

Answer (score 4):

A function $u+iv$ is complex differentiable  if the derivative of $u$ in any direction $h$ is equal to the derivative of $v$ in direction obtained by rotating $h$ by $90$ degrees counterclockwise. This should make sense if you think of imaginary axis as real axis rotated by $90$ degrees counterclockwise.

The Cauchy-Riemann criterion for differentiability  is the observation that it's enough to check the above for horizontal and vertical $h$. (Because these directions span the plane.) This is expressed by 
$$u_x = v_y\quad\text{ and }\quad u_y = - v_x$$
where $-v_x$ is the derivative of $v$ in the direction of negative $x$-axis (the result of rotating the $y$ axis counterclockwise.)

In polar coordinates, we use the radial and tangential directions instead. The rate of change in the tangential direction is $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$ because of angle-distance conversion. Since rotating the positive $r$-direction gives positive $\theta$-direction, 
$$
u_r = \frac{1}{r}v_\theta
$$
And rotating positive $\theta$-direction counterclockwise gives negative $r$-direction, so 
$$
\frac{1}{r}u_\theta = -v_r
$$